# How to calculate $\int_{\frac12 \eta}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{{\lambda}^2}{4 \pi}} {\lambda}^n d{\lambda}$?

Tags: definite-integrals, proof-explanation, estimation

In the following text how the first blue-underlined O-term has changed to the second one?

[image]

I don't know how writing the integrand as $$e^{-\frac{{\lambda}^2}{8 \pi}} \times e^{-\frac{{\lambda}^2}{8 \pi}} {\lambda}^n$$ (up to a factor) helps the conclusion.

Source: Section 4.16. of Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*.

Comment: Since the second term is decreasing, an upper bound comes from substituting the lower bound of the integral into the second factor, taking it out from the integral and then evaluating the integral of the remaining first factor, which is easy.

Comment: @Gary, in the denominator of the exponential which seems to be taken out it appears ${\pi}^2$ and not $\pi$. Evaluation of the rest is not that straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hypothesis mentionned, $$\int_{\eta/2}^\infty e^{-\lambda^2/(8\pi)}\times e^{-\lambda^2/(8\pi)}\left(\frac\lambda{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^nd\lambda\\\le\int_{\eta/2}^\infty e^{-\lambda^2/(8\pi)}\times e^{-\eta^2/(32\pi)}\left(\frac\eta{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^nd\lambda\\\le e^{-\eta^2/(32\pi)}\left(\frac\eta{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^n\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda^2/(8\pi)}d\lambda\\
=O\left(e^{-\eta^2/(32\pi)}\left(\frac\eta{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^n\right)\\
=O\left(e^{-t/16}\left(\frac{\sqrt t}2\right)^n\right).
$$

Comment: in the denominator of the exponential which seems to be taken out it appears ${\pi}^2$ and not $\pi$.

Comment: Also it is not decreasing for all interval and so it is not maximum on the lower bound of interval

Comment: The auhor's $\pi^2$ seems to be a (surprising) misprint.

Comment: No I checked and it goes on with ${\pi}^2$, also the author says that max is not at $\eta /2$ it is at $2 \sqrt{n \pi}$, maybe that's how $\pi^2$ appears?

Comment: Also it *is* "decreasing throughout the interval of integration" under the author's hypothesis, as he explains.